# create scrollable segment control (horizontally)

Tags: swift, uisegmentedcontrol

i am trying to create a scrollable segment control, more precisely i need a segment control that has 5-10 or more choices/buttons but because there will be no space for all that buttons i need it to be scrollable, i need to make the segment control itself to be scrollable. so far i have not see any tutorial for this in swift language or obj c.

[image]

i have tried to put segment control inside a view inside a scrollable view. i then change the width of both VIEW and Scrollable view into 1000. it is scrollable but only a little to the left and little to the right and the button width become very small. i have also try to change the width 
`segmentcontrol.frame.size.width = 100` but it does not make any change. what did i miss??

this is the result[image]

Comment: I know this doesn't directly answer your question, but why not just use a collectionView instead?  I suspect it'd end up being a much easier solution to the problem.

Comment: i didnt choose collectionview because i was going to put 3 scrollableviews in the same page, i am making a filter search result like the one in this link https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/90/ca/e7/90cae7830624fbb4bfcff7e1b2bc1387.jpg

Comment: Did u search https://www.cocoacontrols.com?

Comment: no i have not, thank you for the source i will look into that

Comment: try this : https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the width on the contentSize property of the scrollview? Thats how it knows how much to scroll.

Comment: i checked and the segmencontrol are only set to 158. i change the set to 1000 on scrollview,view,segmentcontrol. but now i cant scroll it at all and the segmentcontrol is unclickable

Comment: It doesn't matter how large the subviews of the scrollview are. All the scrollview cares about is its contentSize. You should make sure you're configuring it:

self.segmentedControl.frame.size.width = 1000; 
self.scrollView.contentSize.width = 1000;

Comment: now i can scroll and click the segment control. but the segment control is not in the center x of the scrollview so the segment is way over to the left. i have make the constraint to be center horizontally in container but it does not make any difference

Comment: Thats good. Yeah. Its probably best to make a CGSize and reuse it for the segmented control and the contentSize of the scrollview.

let size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 20);
segmentedControl.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size);
scrollView.contentSize = size;
scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect.zero, animated: false);

Answer (score -2):

From a UI and usability perspective, it probably makes sense to abandon this kind of custom control. Its not a standard control on iOS. I think on Android its roughly equivalent to their tab view.

It may be better just to use a UIPickerView or push a tableviewcontroller onto the navigation controller stack and list all the options there.

Comment: i am gonna keep looking, but thank you for the help with the content size. i dont know why you -1 btw it wasnt me

Comment: this isn't trying to answer the question. It is an opinion, there-for should be a comment.